# How can I close a materialize Modal in Reactjs without using Jquery/Vanilla Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, materialize

Apparently, am having a **Modal** which I want to close upon a click, to read more about it, visit this link below :

https://react-materialize.github.io/#/modals

But this documentation showed the only way to remove it/ close it they used Jquery, how can I use `state` or other react approach to close it while I have triggered it. For opening it, it's working because the Moadal has the `trigger` property, But now, how can I close it with state/any other React approach?

Below is the modal am having :

```
<Modal
  header='Modal Header'
  trigger={<a href='#' className={attrs.triggerClass}>{attrs.triggerText}</a>}>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</Modal>
```

I'll be very thankful for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this :

```
...    
this.state = { isModalOpen: true }
...
handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
}
...
<Modal open={this.state.isModalOpen}>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>
        Close
    </button>
</Modal>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but since am using redux and am new to it ,am struggling to turn on and off the state of `isModalOpen`

Answer (score 0):

Note: the default state is false and also the setState still remains false

```
  ...    
this.state = { isModalOpen: false }
...
handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false })
}
...
<Modal open={this.state.isModalOpen}>
    <p>Lorem ipsum ...</p>
    <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>
        Close
    </button>
</Modal>
```

This solution has worked for me.